# use homography to rotate around x/y axes 

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, affine-geometry, rigid-transformation

I need to construct a homography out of a 3x3 rotation matrix.  I am fundamentally misunderstanding some part of how homographies are constructed.  I have been assuming that a homography is constructed as follows.

```
hom(0,2) = x translation
hom(1,2) = y translation
hom(2,2) = scale, I can divide the entire matrix by this to normalize
```

The first two columns I assumed were the first two columns of a 3x3 rotation matrix.  This essentially amounts to taking a 3x4 transform and throwing away column(2).  I have discovered however that this is not true.  The test case showing me the error of my ways was trying to make a homography which rotates points some small angle around the y axis.

```
//rotate by .0175 rad about y axis
rot_mat = (1,0,.0174,
           0,1,0,
      -.0174,0,1);
//my conversion method to make this a homography gives

homography = (1,0,0,
              0,1,0,
         -.0174,0,1);
```

The above homography does not work at all.  Take for example a point x,y,1 where x > 58.  The result will be x,y,some_negative_number.  When I convert from homogeneous coordinates back to cartesian my x and y values will both flip signs.

How do I construct a homography that rotates 2D homogeneous points by some angle around the x and y axis?

Answer (score 1):

In the projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^2$ there is no notion of rotation about the $x$- or $y$-axis (nor of any other line in the plane).

Though homographies in $\mathbb{RP}^2$ are represented by $3\times 3$-matrices, they are not to be confused with the linear transformations $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$. The latter are also represented by $3\times 3$-matrices, and can indeed describe the rotations you ask for.